# Rails 5 Has Many Through with Nested Form and Cocoon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, cocoon-gem

**Solverd: see bottom**

I am building a ordering system of many products, with a HBTM from Join Table to anotherModel, but I have some problems when creating and editing a new record of a nested form.

I have tried many solutions from other questions and followed some tutorial like [this](https://www.sitepoint.com/better-nested-attributes-in-rails-with-the-cocoon-gem/) or [this](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon/wiki/A-guide-to-doing-nested-model-forms), but nothing solved my issues.

Product Model:

```
class Product < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :subcategory

  has_many :order_products, inverse_of: :product
  has_many :order, :through => :order_products
end
```

Order Model:

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :order_products, inverse_of: :order
  has_many :products, :through => :order_products

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
end
```

Join Table:

```
class OrderProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :order
  belongs_to :product

  has_and_belongs_to_many :ingredients
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredients, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true    
end
```

Ingredients Model associated with join table: (**many-to-many** to save added ingredients to every products on the order)

```
class Ingredient < ApplicationRecord
  has_and_belongs_to_many :order_products
end
```

Order Controller:

```
  # GET /orders/new
  def new
    @order = Order.new
  end

  # GET /orders/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /orders
  # POST /orders.json
  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.save
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @order }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

    def order_params
      params.require(:order).permit(:subtotal, :discount, :total,
      order_products_attributes: [[:id, :order_id, :product_id , :_destroy]])
    end
```

Views:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order) do |f| %>
  <%= f.error_notification %>

  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.input :subtotal %>
    <%= f.input :discount %>
    <%= f.input :total %>
  </div>

  <%= f.simple_fields_for :order_products do |o| %>
      <%= render 'order_product_fields', f: o %>
  <% end %>

  <%= link_to_add_association "aggiungi prodotto", f, :order_products %>

  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Partial: (unable to add cocoon's destroy link: **undefined method `reflect_on_association' for NilClass:Class** due to auto add of blank fields)

```
<div class="nested-fields order-product-fields">
  <%= f.input :product %>
  <%= f.input :order %>

  <%= f.check_box :_destroy %>

</div>
```

I get this on console:

```
 Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"PRNzrnxk/jrsAyPK5OzFxix2hIUmjCeWpD8Fkuhuhx8Wp3/xYTbTTvsfQkhnMDEBNnC/iNL46kl68XR7skb03g==", "order"=>{"subtotal"=>"", "discount"=>"", "total"=>"", "order_products"=>{"product"=>"", "order"=>"", "_destroy"=>"0"}}, "commit"=>"Create Order"}
Unpermitted parameter: order_products
```

My throubles are: **EDIT: Solution on each point**

1. When I load order pages, **blanks fields for nested attributes are automatically created** ()

**Was wrong nested_attributes on Order Model:**

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for **:order_products**, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

2. When submitting form no entry are created. (but I can add product to order via console .ex: order.products << product1)
3. When I add more product via cocoon's add link, **only first is sent to controller**
4. Don't know how to implements Strong Parameters and views for Ingredient's attributes inside the form of Order

Got this working:

Ingredient model:

```
has_many :ingredient_order_products, inverse_of: :ingredient
has_many :order_products, :through => :ingredient_order_products
```

IngredientOrderProduct model:

```
  belongs_to :ingredient
  belongs_to :order_product
```

Order Product model:

```
  has_many :ingredient_order_products, inverse_of: :order_product
  has_many :ingredients, :through => :ingredient_order_products
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :ingredient_order_products, reject_if: :all_blank, allow_destroy: true
```

Order Controller:

```
def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:customer_id, :subtotal, :discount, :total,
  order_products_attributes: [[:id, :order_id, :product_id, :qty, :gift, :_destroy,
    ingredient_order_products_attributes: [:id, :order_id, :ingredient_id, :_destroy]]])
end
```

_order_product_fields Partial:

```
  <div id="ingredient">
    <%= f.simple_fields_for :ingredient_order_products do |ingredient| %>
      <%= render 'ingredient_order_product_fields', f: ingredient %>
    <% end %>
    <%= link_to_add_association "Aggiungi Ingrediente", f, :ingredient_order_products %>
  </div>
```

Comment: This is weird, everything seems ok. Looking for a typo, but I only found `has_many :order` instead of `:orders` in the `Product` class. The `simple_fields_for` should not be rendering anything (correct association name, form created with the correct object (`@order` --writing `:order` would give errors), the `simple_fields_for` has the `f` in front ...

Comment: I solved all issues 2 days ago. See solutions on bottom. Thank you for commenting.

Comment: Hi Alessandro, glad you managed to solve this issue. Just wanted to not it's a better practice to put the solution in an answer and mark this as resolved. :)